# What is the code to get the Processor Name and Processor Group Name

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there a way in Groovy Code to get the Processor Group Name the ExecuteScript Processor is in and Processor Name of the ExecuteScript Processor the Groovy Code is in. If so what would the code be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To get the processor name, use `ProcessContext#getName()`. The `ProcessContext` class is referenceable from `ExecuteScript` via the provided variable `context`, so the code would be `String processorName = context.getName()`.

To get the process group name, I am not aware of an easy way through the framework code. You can, of course, use the [Apache NiFi REST API](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) to request the list of process groups and iterate through, checking to see if the process group contains a processor with the identifier of the current processor.

Answer (score 1):

to get the name of all the processors and process groups name, you can use
the following code.

```
final EventAccess access = context.getEventAccess();
final ProcessGroupStatus procGroupStatus = access.getControllerStatus();
procGroupStatus.getProcessGroupStatus();
final ProcessorStatus processorstatus = procGroupStatus.getProcessorStatus()
```

ProcessorStatus class contains getName method, which can be used to get the name other processor.

Below is the source code of the same class for your reference.

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/controller/status/ProcessorStatus.java